# Google Container Engine clusters down after upgrading Kubernetes version

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I've upgraded a couple of Google Container Engine clusters from Kubernetes version 1.2.4 to 1.3.5, and according to the UI the upgrade process is finished. However, hitting the corresponding Web servers (which are behind [L7 load balancers AKA GLBCs](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/)) results in error 502 even though it's been about half an hour since the upgrade process finished.

How do I fix/troubleshoot this? I figure it's GLBC that's having trouble, as it's typically returning 502 while transitioning, but I have no idea how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: did you previous set the command line argument `--cluster-uid` to the gce l7 controller? if so please do: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-users/QpsRZcaVmks

Comment: @PrashanthB I can't recall having done so, no.

Comment: @PrashanthB Could you please remind me of the whole process of installing GLBC, in case I've forgot something? It's so hard to find documentation on the thing.

Comment: @PrashanthB Was the cluster UID necessary to avoid conflicts between L7 controllers in different clusters? I just recall having had this problem, but can't remember exactly how I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Seems* as if the ingresses of my different clusters were clashing with each other after the Kubernetes upgrade due to ingress UIDs no longer working or some such, at least that's the current theory. Reinstalling L7 ingresses for all clusters with UIDs reconfigured fixed it.